# Which client should I use for accessing elastic search from an AWS lambda function in java?

Tags: aws-lambda, jest-client

I've been using JestClient and I think it is not good enough.If I try to use the same JestClient instance for subsequent calls, sometimes it doesn't return the response from elastic search and that forces me to reinitialize the JestClient instance again which is an overhead for me.

Comment: I would try measuring the performance of the existing lambda first, to make sure that JestClient is actually the problem

Comment: Yes, you were right JestClient wasn't the problem, there were some unnecessary DynamoDB calls happening while initializing it and those calls were creating the problem.